# Nifi cluster does not spin up using NifiKop

Tags: apache-nifi

I have followed this link https://orange-opensource.github.io/nifikop/docs/next/2_setup/1_getting_started to install nifikop and spin up the cluster however the cluster doesn't seem spin up.

Below are the series of command I executed

Create namespace:

```
kubectl create namespace nifi

kubectl create namespace zookeeper

kubectl create namespace cert-manager
```

Create custom Storageclass

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
name: local-storage
parameters:
type: pd-standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
EOF
```

Create service account

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
name: nifikop
EOF
```

Install zookeeper

```
helm install nifikop-zk bitnami/zookeeper \
--namespace=nifi \
--set resources.requests.memory=256Mi \
--set resources.requests.cpu=250m \
--set resources.limits.memory=256Mi \
--set resources.limits.cpu=250m \
--set networkPolicy.enabled=true \
--set replicaCount=3 \
--set namespaces={“nifi”}
```

Install CRDS

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.1.0/cert-manager.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Orange-OpenSource/nifikop/master/config/crd/bases/nifi.orange.com_nificlusters.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Orange-OpenSource/nifikop/master/config/crd/bases/nifi.orange.com_nifiusers.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Orange-OpenSource/nifikop/master/config/crd/bases/nifi.orange.com_nifiusergroups.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Orange-OpenSource/nifikop/master/config/crd/bases/nifi.orange.com_nifidataflows.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Orange-OpenSource/nifikop/master/config/crd/bases/nifi.orange.com_nifiparametercontexts.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Orange-OpenSource/nifikop/master/config/crd/bases/nifi.orange.com_nifiregistryclients.yaml
```

Install NifiKOP

```
helm install nifikop orange-incubator/nifikop \
--namespace=nifi \
--version="0.4.2-alpha" \
--set resources.requests.memory=256Mi \
--set resources.requests.cpu=250m \
--set resources.limits.memory=256Mi \
--set resources.limits.cpu=250m \
--set namespaces={"nifi"} --skip-crds
```

Create cluster

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -n nifi -f -
apiVersion: nifi.konpyutaika.com/v1
kind: NifiCluster
metadata:
  name: simplenifi
spec:
  service:
    headlessEnabled: true
  zkAddress: "nifikop-zk-zookeeper:2181"
  zkPath: /simplenifi
  clusterImage: "apache/nifi:1.17.0"
  oneNifiNodePerNode: false
  nodeConfigGroups:
    default_group:
      isNode: true
      serviceAccountName: nifikop
      storageConfigs:
        - mountPath: "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs"
          name: logs
          pvcSpec:
            accessModes:
              - ReadWriteOnce
            storageClassName: "local-storage"
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 10Gi
      resourcesRequirements:
        limits:
          cpu: "2"
          memory: 3Gi
        requests:
          cpu: "1"
          memory: 1Gi
  nodes:
    - id: 1
      nodeConfigGroup: "default_group"
    - id: 2
      nodeConfigGroup: "default_group"
  propagateLabels: true
  nifiClusterTaskSpec:
    retryDurationMinutes: 10
  listenersConfig:
    internalListeners:
      - containerPort: 8080
        type: http
        name: http
      - containerPort: 6007
        type: cluster
        name: cluster
      - containerPort: 10000
        type: s2s
        name: s2s
      - containerPort: 9090
        type: prometheus
        name: prometheus
      - containerPort: 6342
        type: load-balance
        name: load-balance

EOF
```

But I can see only these pods under nifi namespace

```
root@bh-gsn-57-asca-dev-01:~/nifikop# k get pods -n nifi
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nifikop-5d6f94854-fjx4q   1/1     Running   0          32m
nifikop-zk-zookeeper-0    1/1     Running   0          39m
nifikop-zk-zookeeper-1    1/1     Running   0          39m
nifikop-zk-zookeeper-2    1/1     Running   0          39m
```

```
root@bh-gsn-57-asca-dev-01:~/nifikop# k get NifiCluster -n nifi
NAME         AGE
simplenifi   19m
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the logs of the nifikop pod with

```
kubectl logs nifikop-5d6f94854-fjx4q -n nifi
```